# Is there an ifelse() function in Jamovi

Tags: if-statement, nested, statistics, jamovi

Am new to Jamovi and wonderfully lost!

Wondering if I can use the following ifelse() function in computing an new variable:

```
NEWVariable = ifelse(p20freekit_1 == 1,1,ifelse(p20freekit_2 == 1,2,ifelse(p20freekit_3 == 1,3,ifelse(p20freekit_4 == 1,4,ifelse(p20freekit_5 == 1,5,0 )))))
```

This works in R as far as I know.

Am wondering how to do it in Jamovi.

Thanks for any hints.

Leo